# Nautilus will open but it won't show an item on the launcher so I can't lock it

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus

When I open Files (Nautilus), nothing will show up on my launcher so I can't lock it or go back to an old window of it without minimizing my other apps.

Anyway to fix that?

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: You need to describe your problem better. Isn't there a `Files` icon in your launcher now?

Comment: No, I removed the Files icon from the launcher because it wasn't showing already opened windows. It would open a new window without issues but it wouldn't let me switch opened windows. I figured if I opened it again then I would be able to pin it again but it never showed up again.

Comment: Search for 'Files` in the Unity dashboard, and then just drag its icon back to the launcher.

Comment: :) thanks, that let me lock it in place. I guess I should make another question then because I'm still unable to select already opened windows by clicking on it on the launcher.

Comment: If you right-click on the `Files` icon, you'll see the pre-defined folders that you can jump to. If you'd like to add to that list, just create your own bookmarks by dragging folders into the lower-left pane of an open `Files` window.

Comment: So is it normal for it not to show all opened windows when you press on it? I can swear it used to do that.

Comment: I don't recall. Maybe with a Nautilus extension?